# Trying to run curl from Jira

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

While trying to run CURL command from JIRA i am getting below error:

2017-04-04 18:18:37,351 ERROR [workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction]: *************************************************************************************
2017-04-04 18:18:37,351 ERROR [workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction]: Script function failed on issue: JI-1, actionId: 21, file: 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at Script147.run(Script147.groovy:47)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    ... 1 more

Comment: Provide your script? My guess would be that you need to specify the full path to the `curl` binary.

Comment: log.debug "curl -1 -k --user *******:******** -X POST $url?OBNumber=$id -H Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded -H .crumb:*******"

println "curl -1 -k --user *****:********* -X POST $url?OBNumber=$id -H Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded -H .crumb:*******".execute().text;

Comment: import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLink;

Comment: So, what happens if you try to specify the full path for CURL?

Comment: What you mean by full path ? I have added it in environment variable in my windows system. How to provide the exact path in Jira. Do i need to do something specific with regards to Jira.

Comment: I meant to use "c:\temp\curl.exe -1 -k ..." since I am not sure if .execute() will use the PATH you have declared. If the curl executable is in a directory that contains spaces, you may also need to quote it in your string (or move curl somewhere else).

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Great! I added the above comment as an answer. If it works for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that you will need to specify the full path to the `curl` executable, such as below:

```
"c:\temp\curl.exe -1 -k ..."
```

If the `curl` executable is in a directory that contains spaces, you will either need to add the appropriate quoting to the string or else move the `curl` executable somewhere that does not have that problem.